# How can I implement a check constraint for attribute ID to start with specified letters?

Tags: sql, sqlite, glob, sql-like, check-constraints

I want my attribute ID to start with the letters AB, followed by exactly 8 integers. And how would I do it, when I want it to start and end with defined letters?

```
CREATE TABLE Table(
    ID TEXT NOT NULL 
        PRIMARY KEY 
        CHECK (ID LIKE AB________')
);
```

Answer (score 3):

Use the [GLOB](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_expr.html#the_like_glob_regexp_match_and_extract_operators) operator:

```
CHECK (ID GLOB 'AB[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]')
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/WsuuE-3q).

Or:

```
CHECK (ID GLOB 'AB' || REPLACE(HEX(ZEROBLOB(8)), '00', '[0-9]'))
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/EgtYR4mV).